# h:message not displayed in jsf page

Tags: java, jsf

I made a simple login page in jsf with a login field.  If the login is not correct (no user found in the database) a message should appear on the page but nothing is displayed...
ps : If the user enter nothing, the message specified in the "requiredMessage" is displayed.
This is the code of my jsf page :

```
<h:body>
        <p>Identification</p>
        <h:form prependId="false">           
            login : <h:inputText id="log" value="#{filesystemCtrl.login}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter your username"/>
            <h:message for="log" style="color:red"/><br/>
            <h:commandButton action="#{filesystemCtrl.identifier()}" value="Login"/>
        </h:form>
        <div id="footer" align="center">
            <ui:insert name="footer">


             <ui:include src="footer.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert >
        </div>
    </h:body>
```

And this is a part of the managedBean :

```
public String identifier() {
        client = filesystemFacade.identifier(login);
        if (client == null) {
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context.addMessage("log", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error", "No user found !"));
            return "failure";
        } else {
            return "success";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action method returns a navigation case in all paths. I'm guessing you don't actually have a `failure` navigation (i.e. a `failure.xhtml` view) so when your `client` object is null, you still see the same view without the update message. What should happen is get a redirection to `failure` view, and by this, the browser will have no chance to display the error message. Check your server logs for navigation errors.

Since you want the browser to stay on the same page (view) and update the error message, your method should return `null` after adding the message, instead of `failure`.

Comment: Thank's that's right ! I return null as you say to stay on the same page and now I see the message.

Answer (score -1):

You need to update the message component after the post-back. Give it an id as

```
<h:message for="log" id="msgLog" style="color:red"/><br/>
```

and then change your button to

```
<h:commandButton action="#{filesystemCtrl.identifier()}" value="Login" 
update="msgLog" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: Firstly, you meant a command button from PrimeFaces and used the JSF version that doesn't have the update attribute. Secondly, OP nowere stated that he intended to use AJAX so you should seek for the problem during synchronous request processing. I'll remove my downvote as soon as you find the solution to the given problem.

Comment: I stand corrected. Please disregard this answer, I posted another one.

Answer (score -1):

The javadoc of addMessage writes:

> Append a FacesMessage to the set of messages associated with the specified client identifier, if clientId is not null.

You have passed the component id. That's not the same. Hence your message might be associated with a non-existing component, and therefore not displayed.

The algorithm for forming the client identifier is described by the javadoc of [`UIComponent.getClientId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getClientId%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29).

On a more practical note, I'd set a breakpoint in the renderer of h:message to discover what identifier it expects to display the message.

Comment: You'd be right, and that was my initial thought, if it were not for the fact that `prependId="false"`. The possible problem is that OP returns a navigation case outcome from the action method. The message part is awkward, but should work just fine.

Comment: Right, it should. But does it? Perhaps the commandLink renderer duplicates the algorithm for clientId computation, and wasn't updated to respect prependId. In any case, the best way to discover why nothing is rendered is to set a breakpoint in the renderer, and check the clientId it expects.